# Set a hex registry value with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I have a Registration Entries (.reg) file, and I wanted to convert it to a PowerShell script.

On my way, I encountered this value: `hex:00`.

Here is the registry key & value that I want to set:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{042D8A51-5878-4000-9C10-C04AFF122A1F}"`

`"Triggers"=hex:00`

How do I set this Hex value using Set-ItemPropery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use [`Set-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty) to target *registry* paths, the cmdlet supports a dynamic parameter named `-Type` that accepts a [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) value, which specifies the value's data type.

The presence of `hex:` in your `*.reg` file implies *binary* (raw bytes) as the data type; therefore:

- pass `Binary` to `-Type`
- pass the binary value (data) as an *array of bytes* to `-Value`; to produce the equivalent of `hex:00` - i.e. a single byte with value `0x0` - use `-Value 0x0` (to pass *multiple* bytes, separate them with `,` e.g.: `-Value 0x0, 0x1`):

```sh
Set-ItemProperty -Type Binary -Value 0x0 -Name Triggers -LiteralPath 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Schedule\TaskCache\Tasks\{042D8A51-5878-4000-9C10-C04AFF122A1F}'
```

Also note the `registry::` prefix to the registry key path, which is required to identify the path as a *registry* path (in a context-independent manner).

Alternatively, replace `registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` with `HKLM:`, to base the path on the equivalent [*PowerShell-specific drive*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) instead. (The other predefined registry drive is `HKCU:`, which is equivalent to `registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER`; [`Get-PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-psdrive)`-PSProvider registry` shows all registry-based drives).